# Add Parameters to a GET Requests using Google App Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, get-request

```
URL/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq
```

**URL**: URL/V1/products

**Params to pass:**

1. searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name
2. searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10
3. searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq

**Method**: GET

I would like to pass the URL parameters in this way:

```
function getProducts() {

 var params = {
 searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]:name,
 searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]:10,
 searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​:eq
}

var options = {
'headers': {
'Content-Type': "application/json",
'Accept': "application/json",
'Authorization': TOKEN,
'method': "get",
'Request': params
}
};

  var url = 'URL/rest/V1/products';
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Cooper I am trying to add the URL parameters not direct in the URL but using the headers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I am trying to add the URL parameters not direct in the URL but using the headers.`. I apologize for this. At the specification of the API you want to use, the query parameter can be included in the request header? For example, in order to confirm the specification, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?